# Trying to use speechSynthesis in Angular2 with IWindow Interface

Tags: angular, interface, window, angular2-services, speech-synthesis

I'm trying to use the speechSynthesis
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-speech-synthesis-api

First I extended the window with an interface:

window.interface.ts

```
export interface IWindow extends Window {
  webkitSpeechRecognition: any;
  speechSynthesis: any;
}
```

Next I made a window service:

window.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IWindow } from '../interfaces/window-interface';

function _window() : IWindow {
   return window;
}
@Injectable()
export class WindowService {
   get nativeWindow() : any {
      return _window();
   }
}
```

Now in the component, I'm trying to implement it.... without success..

app.component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { WindowService } from '../../providers/window.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['.app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private _router: Router, private _window: WindowService ) { }

   sayIt() {
      var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World');
      this._window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
   }
}
```

TS Error:

```
Cannot find name 'SpeechSynthesisUtterance'.)
Property 'speechSynthesis' does not exist on type 'WindowService'.)
```

I used this article on speech recognition as a reference also: [Angular2: Web Speech API - Voice recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087013/angular2-web-speech-api-voice-recognition)

Still getting error --
    Property 'speechSynthesis' does not exist on type 'Window'

Comment: Still getting the error: 
Property 'speechSynthesis' does not exist on type 'Window'

Comment: I have the same error Cannot find name 'SpeechSynthesisUtterance' The problem is in TypeScript, I resolved using a Javascript script in Angular. [Look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081943/angular2-import-external-js-file-into-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done as below

```
 var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("hello world");
 (<any>window).speechSynthesis.speak(msg)
```

Got help from the link

> [SpeechRecognition and SpeechSynthesis in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740683/speechrecognition-and-speechsynthesis-in-typescript)