# @kamiazya ngx-speech-recognition missing types with Typescript@4.4+

Tags: typescript, types, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

**Package**
@kamiazya/ngx-speech-recognition

Missing Types: SpeechGrammar, SpeechGrammarList, SpeechRecognition, SpeechRecognitionErrorEvent, SpeechRecognitionEvent, webkitSpeechGrammarList, webkitSpeechRecognition, webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent

**Error**

TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpeechRecognitionError'.

> `ERROR in node_modules/@kamiazya/ngx-speech-recognition/lib/service/speech-recognition.token.d.ts: 16:73 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpeechRecognitionError'.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

TypeScript 4.4 libdom changes

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/1029

**Solution**

npm install --save @types/dom-speech-recognition

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dom-speech-recognition